# get values into redux form field from another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I implemented the google map component to view current location and marker drag functionality by using [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) now i want to fill my redux form field with latitude and longitude i tried this way

**Location.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Location extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lat: null,
      lng: null,
      markers: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>
      this.setState({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      })
    );
  }

  onMarkerDragEnd = coord => {
    const { latLng } = coord;
    const lat = latLng.lat();
    const lng = latLng.lng();

    this.setState({
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    });

    console.log(lat, lng);

  };

  render() {
    if (!this.props.loaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    const style = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100vh"
    };
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={11}
        style={style}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: this.state.lat,
          lng: this.state.lng
        }}
        center={{
          lat: this.state.lat,
          lng: this.state.lng
        }}
        onClick={this.mapClicked}
      >
        <Marker
          title={"Geolocation"}
          position={{
            lat: this.state.lat,
            lng: this.state.lng
          }}
          draggable={true}
          onDragend={(t, map, coord) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(coord)}
        />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

const selector = formValueSelector("registershop");

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  //
  //
};

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "......"
})(connect(mapStateToProps)(Location));
```

**Register.JS**

```
import Location from "../common/Location";
    class Register extends Component {
   const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
     <div>
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
     <label>Lat:</label>
     <Field name="lat" component="input" type="number" step="0.01" />
     <label>Lng:</label>
     <Field name="lng" component="input" type="number" step="0.01" />
     </form>
<Location/>
<div>
)
    }
```

when user **route to the register component i want to show** his/her current location for that i used **componentDidMount** and also i wanted to give chance to user select their location by drag the marker

I'm new to redux form so i don't have better idea for how to bind longitude and latitude to the reduxform to the submit please help me

Comment: Not sure if you meant to use redux-form for your Register.js and trying to get initial value from state. If that's the case this should help: https://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/initializefromstate/

Comment: no i want to get data from location.js component  to  two redux form field called lat and lng in  register.js component